# Open JSON File in Rails and Stimulus

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

I have a select form which determines which values are shown in a table. The values are stored in a json file. My Question is: what is the best way to do this cuz i have a gut feeling smth might be wrong with my solution.

Im able to open the json file and save it in a json/jbuilder object in my controller and then call the object in my view and pass the json in the select which calls a stimulus function, which then handles what is shown on the table.

Main Controller:

```
class MainController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @itemsJSON = JSON.parse(File.read('db/data.json'))
    end
end
```

Index View

```
<%= form_with do |form| %>
  <%= form.select :city, [['all'], ['critical'],['error'],['warning'],['info'],['debug']], 
        { prompt: "Select Item Type" },
        data: { controller: "dropdownTable", value: @itemsJSON, 
        action: "change >dropdownTable#selectData"} %>
<% end %>
```

Stimulus Function

```
Code that doesnt work gives back error: localhost:8080/main/db/database.json not found which // i dont understand why 

//fetch('/db/data.json')
//    .then((response) => response.json())
//    .then((json) => console.log(json));


export default class extends Controller {
    selectData(event){
        ... code that works
    }
}
```

Comment: Static files, accessible to the internet, need to go in `public`, not in `db`.

Comment: @user229044 i moved the file to the public folder and then i tried 
`fetch('public/data.json')` but it still gave me the same error **localhost:8080/public/data.json not found**

Comment: "what is the best way to do this cuz i have a gut feeling smth might be wrong with my solution." - Sorry dude but the problem is literally your whole solution. Use a database instead of JSON file as your storage - which is a dead end path. Write meaningful controllers that expose that data in a RESTful way.